# Cauchy sequence and $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \Vert a_{k+1} - a_{k} \Vert^{2} < \infty$. What is the relationship?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I am wondering what are the relationships of the following three statements (the sequence $\{ a_{k} \} \in \mathbb{C}^{N}$ here is assumed to be bounded):

1. $\{ a_{k} \}$ is a Cauchy sequence.
2. $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \Vert a_{k+1} - a_{k} \Vert^{2}  < \infty$.
3. $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \Vert a_{k+1} - a_{k} \Vert  < \infty$

Right now, I only know that 3. implies 1. Without the boundedness assumption, 2. does not imply 1. But what if there is boundedness assumption?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the $a_k$ are bounded, (2) does not imply (1).

Say $$a_k=\sum_{n=1}^k\pm\frac1n.$$

Then (2) holds regardless of how we choose the $\pm$ signs. I imagine you noticed that if we take all plus signs then $(a_k)$ is not Cauchy, but also not bounded. If we take alternating plus and minus signs then $(a_k)$ *is* Cauchy, by the alternating series test.

So do something in between: Take enough plus signs until you get an $a_{k_1}>1$, then switch to minus signs until you get to $k_2>k_1$ with $a_{k_2}<0$, then switch back to plus signs until $a_{k_3}>1$... Then $(a_k)$ is not Cauchy, because $\limsup a_k\ge1$ and $\liminf a_k\le0$, but we have $-1\le a_k\le 2$ for all $k$.

**Edit:** Oh. Quicker but less interesting: Let $a_k=\sin(\log(k))$.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. Very good example. It is a slowly oscillating sequence that ensures $a_{k}$ and $a_{k+1}$ close to each other well enough but still oscillating between 0 and 1 and thus is not convergent.

Comment: Now we know:
3. $\Rightarrow$ 1. (I can show that) but 1. $\not \Rightarrow$ 3. (consider $a_{k} = \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}$) ;
3.  $\Rightarrow$ 2. but 2. $\not \Rightarrow$ 3. (obvious) ;
2. $\not \Rightarrow$ 1. (as your example indicates ) ;
The remain question is 1. $\Rightarrow$ 2 or 1. $\not \Rightarrow$ 2?

Comment: @Peter You can show (1) does not imply (2) by a simple example just like your example showing (1) does not imply (3).

Comment: Oh. yean. Just take $a_{k} = \frac{(-1)^{k}}{\sqrt{k}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ullrich. The relationships are as depicted.
[image: The relationships are]